# How to see all plugins installed in Phonegap/Cordova project?

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I need to see the list of all installed Cordova plugins.

Does somebody know how to do this?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Just type

```
cordova plugin ls
```

or

```
cordova plugin list
```

on command line in your project's root folder where you would normally install or remove your plugins, or build or run it.

Answer (score 17):

The newer versions of Cordova also support the following:

```
cordova plugin
```

or

```
cordova plugins
```

Answer (score 1):

for the capacitor cli `npx cap ls`

Answer (score 0):

For ionic `ionic cordova plugin list`